# Another log4net, fluent nhibernate configuration issue

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, log4net

This is driving me crazy... I've spent half a day trying to turn everything aroung but I can't get log4net to spit out anything about NHibernate.

Here's my current Fluent NHibernate config:

```
var configuration = Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.UsingFile(AppConstants.PATH_FILENAME_DB))
    .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<...>())
    [...Mappings...]
    .Diagnostics(x => x.Enable());
```

My app.config:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
</configSections>

<log4net>
  <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="data/log/unprocessed.log"/>
    <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <logger name="NHibernate.SQL" additivity="false">
    <level value="ALL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender"/>
  </logger>

  <root>
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender"/>
  </root>
</log4net>
```

I can log stuff right after I initialize the main form:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
logger.Info("Here is a debug log!!");
```

And it works 100%. However I'm not able to get anything out of Nhibernate.

I've tried:

- setting ShowSql() in my Fluent NHibernate config => SQL appears in VS console.
- adding NHibernate logger
- removing additivity
- using ConsoleAppender instead of LogFileAppender (still no SQL in the output though I get regular logs from the application)
- recompiling Fluent NHibernate, tried 3 different versions of log4net...

My Fluent Nhibernate mappings are good, my app is working perfectly without log4net.

I still am unable to log any queries from NHibernate... Not sure what is going on but if you have a clue I'll be happy to try it out!!!

Thanks!

Comment: which version of NHibernate do you use? is NHibernate.dll in the same folder as log4net.dll?

Comment: Check that the version of log4net that you're referencing in your main proect is the same as the version that NHibernate is referencing.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. I'm using the latest version of NHibernate (3.3.0.4) and the log4net dll (1.2.10) located in its test folder (since NHibernate doesn't have the log4net dependance anymore). I've recompiled FluentNhibernate in .net 4.0 using the DLLs from NHibernate 3.3.0.4 and used all 3 DLLs in my application. Yes all DLLs are in the same folder.

Comment: Thanks guys, I found the issue thanks to Firo's comment... See the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I ended up finding the issue...

All my DLLs were located in /lib folder instead of the output folder.

Part of my app.config had this:

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <probing privatePath="lib"/>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Putting log4net.dll in my output folder fixed the issue.